# Something is really wrong with either ADT theory or how it is treated in programming languages?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, type-theory, unit-type

I am not a mathematician, but i feel some logical problems are there.

Lets start from the ADT primitives, for example "unit" type. It should play role of "1" in the context of type set. But in fact, we see "unit" type often called equivalent of "void" in C, C++, etc. At the same time we've our own "void" type in ADT, which plays role of "0", and really defines NO values of itself.

Some opinions on that sounds like "unit type brings no information, therefore it is useless and we can think of it as of void-like". But where is C void equivalent? Or, void = unit, "0=1"? It is bad idea bringing some paradoxes.

Then, lets go deeper. Unit type defines only one value, okay. But, why in ADT theory

```
unit + unit = 2*unit
```

when we should get unit? "+" works like "or" defining type that we know as variant types.
"unit or unit" definitely doesn't give us "bits", or anything more complex to continue.

Mention haskell tuples, which doesn't have even tuple of single element but can be empty.
So it's from ADT theory too. Tuple is a multiplication of item types, therefore one element tuple is the same as that naked element, and empty tuple is unit value ().

```
a == (a) == ((a)) == ...
() == (()) == ...
```

So, a paradox here is: what length does have an empty tuple? As you can see, its length is zero and one at the same time...

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminated_union

Answer (score 13):

First, we need to disregard C-like languages etc.: those don't even try to match the mathematical foundations.

Haskell and other functional languages do try this, and while it's often not obvious how the isomorphisms work they are there.

> Then, lets go deeper. Unit type defines only one value, okay. But, why in ADT theory
>
> ```
> unit + unit = 2*unit
> ```
>
> when we should get unit? "+" works like "or" defining type that we know as variant types. "unit or unit" definitely doesn't give us "bits", or anything more complex to continue.

Well, yes, it does give us bits.

```
type Bit = Either () ()

(||), (&&) :: Bit -> Bit -> Bit

(Left()) || (Left()) = Left()
_ || _ = Right()

(Right()) && (Right()) = Right()
_ && _ = Left()
```

If you don't believe it works:

> Prelude Acme.Missiles> type Bit = Either () ()
> Prelude Acme.Missiles> let [true, false] = [Left (), Right ()] :: [Bit]
> Prelude Acme.Missiles> if true==false then launchMissiles else return ()
> Loading package stm-2.4.2 ... linking ... done.
> Loading package acme-missiles-0.3 ... linking ... done.
> Prelude Acme.Missiles>

Ah, thank goodness, we're still alive...

---

As for "nested unit tuples": those just represent the fact that `1ⁿ ≡ 1`.

---

Perhaps things become clearer when we actually consider the zero type as well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

data Void
```

now, let's go through the simplest cases:

- **0*0 = 0**. Since we can not offer a value for either side of the tuple, we can't define a value of type `(Void, Void) ≅ Void`.
- **0+0 = 0**. While `Either` gives use two constructors, both require a `Void` argument which we can't provide, so we still have `Either Void Void ≅ Void`.
- **0*1 = 0**. We can't construct a `(Void, ())` because we can't provide a value for the `fst`.
- **0+1 = 1**. Aha! We can't construct the `Left`, but we can do `Right ()`! So `Either Void () ≅ ()`, because that is the single value of this type.
- **1*1 = 1**. Both sides of the tuple can only take on the value `()`.
- **1+1 = 2**. That's the case I dicussed above, it has the distinct values `Left ()` and `Right ()`.
- **2+3 = ...** *darn, [I've chosen the wrong programming language for explaining this!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nvs5pqf-DMA)* BTW, ⟂ is right out...

Comment: What difference is between left () and right ()? By definition they are completely equal, the same. So we need some ad-hoc magic here to make all system work.

Comment: Anyway, which length the tuple with "nested unit tuples" has? Zero or one?

Comment: No, there is nothing ad-hoc. It's just that `+` in ADT theory does _not_ work like "or", and nor does `Either` in Haskell: it keeps track of which field is used, regardless of whether both have the same type. — "Length of a tuple" is not defined, so there's no reason to talk about that.

Comment: @user3002392 No, they're not the same. They contain the same amount of information, but they are distinguishable.  That's like saying True and False are the same, because they convey the same amount of information.

Comment: @Carl Ok, how does differ one integer number 5 from other integer number 5? They are the same. Why unit value behaves other way?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Length of a tuple is not defined? Then, why do we speak about two-element tuples, called pairs, three element tuples and so on. (a, b, c, d) has length of 4. It's obvious here..

Comment: @user3002392: `(a,b,c,d)` is isomorphic to `((a,b),(c,d))`, so you could equally well say its length is two.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Isomorphic =/= equal, it is different values, diffrenet structures. Yes, they are isomorphic even to similar list, but i cannot treat tuple as list or anything other. But () _equals_ to (()). Just as (a) means a. It is not in haskell context, but in common.

Comment: About upd answer: I believe it works. But looks tricky and unessential. There are many ways to define algebraic types system, i want to understand why this one is better.

Comment: Stop. In the example we define unit*unit which seems to be bits, of course, what about unit + unit? It results in unit.

Comment: Those tuples are not isomorphic to any "similar list". — Of course you're right that Haskell treats those types as different, but that happens at the _type system level_. The type system merely gives us a framework in which we can have representatives of ADT objects. OTOH, the statement "it is different values" doesn't make sense for `(a,b,c,d)` vs `((a,b),(c,d))`: values of those types can neither be equal nor different, because the type system doesn't allow us to `==` them. But there exists (neglecting ⟂) a _unique_ isomorphism `sp :: (a,b,c,d)->((a,b),(c,d))`, WRT which they are identical.

Comment: "In the example we define unit*unit" — no we don't. That would in fact be unit again, by means of `((), ()) ≅ ()`. (There is only one non-⟂ value of type `((), ())`, namely `((), ())`).

Comment: a * b gives a pair (a, b), a + b gives a variant type a or b. int*int = (int, int), int + int = int | int. in the example we have combination, or pair (), () so i think it is () * ()
I use terminology as in http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011

Comment: @user3002392: you also mentioned "how does differ one integer number 5 from other integer number 5? They are the same. Why unit value behaves other way?" The unit value does not behave any other way from other types. Consider `2+2`, or `Either (Either()()) (Either()())`, which has the _four_ values `Left(Left())`, `(Left(Right())`, `Right(Left())`, and `Right(Right())`. For integers, you get the (different!) values e.g. `Left 2` and `Right 2`.

Comment: Ok, we force them to be different by boxing. Huh, it really gives explanation, but looks like a trick. Then we need to say also we add or multiply not types, but their wrappers, which are different because of their position.

Comment: @user3002392 If you did not take into consideration "their wrappers" (which are as much part of the value as anything else) you would not have ADTs anymore. The strenght of ADTs lies in being able to combine type and distinguish different combinations. Imagine how useless `Either` would be if you could not tell the difference between `Left "Unexpected symbol on line 3, column 5"` and `Right "if x == 5:"` -- we would be back to using only strings again!

Comment: Why not using just "Left | Right" or "Zero | One". We need no unit values at all.

Comment: @user3002392: because `Either` is not _really_ made for this trivial (however conceptually important) special case, but for `+`ing together actual contentful Haskell types. We have `Bool` for the ADT-2.

Comment: "Nested unit tuple" is a contradiction in terms. It can't be unit if it has something inside it. This is in contrast to `Identity` for instance, which would be an example of a type that contains exactly one value.

Comment: Haskell doesn't come with a predefined type for 1-tuples.  (e) is not a 1-tuple.